# Show that if n is an integer and 3n+ 2 is even, then n is even using contradiction

Tags: logic

Show that if $n$ is an integer and $3n+ 2$ is even, then $n$ is even,  using a proof by contradiction.

That's the question. So since we're using contradiction, I need to show that N is odd and prove a contradiction exists, right?

$N = 2k + 1$

$3(2k + 1) + 1=6k + 5\quad$ ?

I think I'm off base, or else I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: $3(2k+1)+1$ should be $6k + 4$ and so is even.

Answer (score 2):

Use these facts:

$\mbox{odd}\times\mbox{odd}=\mbox{odd}$
$\mbox{odd}+\mbox{even}=\mbox{odd}$

Thus, if $n$ was odd, then:

$3n+2=\mbox{odd}\!\times\!\mbox{odd}+\mbox{even}=\mbox{odd}+\mbox{even}=\mbox{odd}$

But we know that $3n+2$ is even - thus, $n$ can't be odd.

---

Another way of doing it: Say $n$ is odd. Thus, there exists a $k$ such that $n=2k+1$. Then:

$$3n+2\overset{n=2k+1}=3(2k+1)+2=6k+3+2=6k+5=6k+4+1=2(3k+2)+1$$

Anything of the form $2j+1$ is odd. (In this case, $j=3k+2$.) Thus, we have that $3n+2$ is odd.

But we know that $3n+2$ is even - thus, $n$ can't be odd.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly right! Since:
$$
3n + 2 = 6k + 5 = 2(\underbrace{3k + 2}_{\in ~ \mathbb Z}) + 1
$$
it follows that $3n + 2$ is odd, contradicting the fact that $3n + 2$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Just write $3n + 2 = n + 2(n +1)$ or $(3n + 2) - 2(n+1) = n$ and then note that the difference and sum of even numbers must be even.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a fine start, but it is good, in such a proof, to state clearly what is given, and what we are assuming for the sake of contradiction.

---

Let $n$ be an integer such that $3n+2$ is even.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $n$ is odd.

Then there exists an integer $k$ such that $n = 2k+1$.

So, $$3n + 2 = 3(2k+1) + 2 = 6k + 3 + 2 = 6k + 5 = 6k +4 + 1 = 2(3k+2) + 1$$

Since $k$ is an integer, so is $3k+2 = \mathcal l$. This means that $3n+2$ is of the form $2\mathcal l + 1$, and hence is odd.

But this contradicts the fact that we are given $3n+2$ is even.

Hence, $n$ cannot be odd, as we supposed. Thus, we have proven that in fact, $n$ must be even if $2n+3$ is even.

Answer (score -1):

$3n+2=2k$

$n=2k-2n-2$

$n=2(k-n-1)$

$n=2b$

Hence $3n+2$ is even when $n$ is even therefore also odd when $n$ is odd.